# query dont want to work very well ^^

Tags: sql, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM _Inventory 
where ItemID = ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM _Items 
    WHERE RefItemID IN ( 46440 , 46441 , 46442 ) 
        AND ID64 = @ID64 )
```

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IN` and specify a field from your items table (instead of specifying *):

```
DELETE FROM _Inventory 
WHERE ItemID IN (
    SELECT ItemId 
    FROM _Items 
    WHERE RefItemID IN ( 46440 , 46441 , 46442 ) AND ID64 = @ID64 )
```

Comment: @KimoAtomix -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

simply use `IN`

```
DELETE 
FROM _Inventory 
where ItemID IN ( SELECT ItemID 
                  FROM _Items 
                  WHERE RefItemID IN (46440 ,46441 ,46442) 
                        AND ID64 = @ID64 
                )
```

or by using `JOIN` which I more prefer,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    _Inventory a
        INNER JOIN _Items b
            ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID
WHERE   b.RefItemID IN (46440, 46441, 46442) AND
        b.ID64 = @ID64
```

Comment: I too like the JOIN, but it won't work with every RDBMS (Oracle for example).

Answer (score 0):

the star should be replaced with the correct column name. Also make sure the subquery returns only one row. Not multiple rows. If multiple rows, then need to change your equality comparison to a IN clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `SELECT ItemID FROM _Items ...`.  The error is pretty clear: your subquery is not allowed to return more than one column because `ItemID` can only be compared to the single column.  In `EXISTS` this would be equivalent to returning `1` or `0`, which is still a single column and thus allowed.

Comment: guys i have some querys , but iam not sure if they are right or not     look at them

Comment: @KimoAtomix why don't you just test them out?

Comment: oky but how i can put the query in a window like you guys do ? sorry for this stupid question ^^

Comment: @KimoAtomix maybe try sqlfiddle.com